# improper import of data from csv through pandas in python 3. (Data in one column with separator as \)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I am trying to import data from a csv file using pandas. The file is directly generated through Aginity Workbench as an out of a SQL query. CSV has over 17 columns but on being imported it is showing only 1 column. The following is what I get when I see the dataframe post import:

id\col1\col2\col3\col4\col5\col6\…\col16

and the first row of data looks like

0        2018-02-25 00:00:00.000000\t5a929e4f4c9672e62a...

I tried using sep = ""\" but it didn't work. Seeking help how to import this data in formatted manner.

Comment: The '\' acts as an escape character in strings, try using `sep = "\\"`.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, Output is still the same.